# how to loop in Two Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects like this

```
let a = { pending: '500', answer: '200', reject: '400' }
let b ={ Pending: 'pending', Answer: 'answer', Reject: 'reject' }
```

and now I want loop in the objects for this like:

```
const C = [{status:200,title:"answer"},{status:400,title:"reject"}, {status:500,title:"pendeing"}]
```

i can do it?? how

Comment: How is object `b` being used here? Can't you obtain your output using just `a` ?

Comment: `Object.entries(a).map( ([status, title]) => ({status, title}) )`

Comment: @AvinashThakur you switched status and title ... The result of your mapping is `[{status: "pending", title: "500"}, ...]`  futhermore the statuscode is a string instead of a number ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just you can use a array and a object

```js
let Object1 = { pending: '500', answer: '200', reject: '400' }
let Object2 =['pending', 'answer',  'reject']

let array =[]

for (let i = 0; i<Object2.length; i++) {
  array.push({status: Object1[Object2[i]], title:Object2[i]})
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think b must be a tab like this:

```
let b = ['pending', 'answer', 'reject']
```

And we can have c with this code:

```js
var a = { pending: '500', answer: '200', reject: '400' }
var b =['pending', 'answer',  'reject']

let c =[]

for (let i = 0; i<b.length; i++) {
  c.push({status: a[b[i]], title:b[i]})
}

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need `b` for that at all

The simplest would probably be

```js
var a = { pending: '500', answer: '200', reject: '400' }
var c = Object.entries(a).map(([title, status]) => ({status: +status, title}))
console.log(c);
```